# Creating Subtypes in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, subtype

I want to create Subtypes for a feature class, but the option is not active.

Under Feature Class Property I created some Fields, but the Subtypes tab is not active.

I can't choose Subtype Field and can't type under Code or Description.

I did try to create subtypes for another map, even open a new document and created a new File Geodatabase, new feature class, but Subtype Tab is not working.

I am using ArcMap 10.7.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for my problem.

You can't create Subtypes if at least one of the Fields is not settled as Short Integer, to use it in Subtype Field.

Maybe it could exist another explanation, but for me this solution worked.